A finite group with specified Class Equation
This question was closed for lack of context, but I think it deserves some attention, namely a proof or a counterexample. So, here I pose it again, providing hopefully enough context to make it suitable for this site (to give it credit, I keep the same title). I report here the claim:
Claim. Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$, whose class equation is:
$$2n=1+\underbrace{2+\dots+2}_{(n-2)\text{ terms}}+3$$Then $n=3$ (and $G\cong S_3\cong D_3$).
Some possibly useful general facts:

$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts on the set $X$ of the conjugacy classes of $G$ in the natural way (let's call $\varphi$ this action);
the kernel of this action contains $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, because every inner automorphism fixes every conjugacy class;
automorphisms preserve the order of the elements and the size on the conjugacy classes.

Now down to claim's setting. For 3, every automorphism fixes the unique singleton class and the unique class of size $3$. Therefore, $\operatorname{im}\varphi\cong K\le S_{n-2}$. Moreover, $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)\cong G$, because $G$ is centerless, and hence $\left|\operatorname{Inn}(G)\right|=2n$. For 2:
\begin{alignat}{1}
|\operatorname{im}\varphi|=\frac{(n-2)!}{k}=\frac{\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G)\right|}{|\ker\varphi|}\le\frac{\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G)\right|}{2n} \\
\end{alignat}
for some integer $k$, $1\le k\le(n-2)!$, whence:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G)\right|\ge\frac{2n(n-2)!}{k} \\
\end{alignat}
I think that to make some progress along this line, we need to have information/make assumptions on the actual orders of the elements in the conjugacy classes of size $2$.
For the case $n$ odd, we could also argue as follows. Since there are conjugacy classes of size $2$, then there are normal centralizers (as their index in $G$ is $2$). Say $N$ one of them. Let $x∈G$ have order $2$ (it exists by Cauchy). If $n(=|N|)$ is odd, then $N∩⟨x⟩=1$, and hence $G≅⟨x⟩⋉N$. Maybe is there any result on the conjugacy classes of a semidirect product which conflicts with $G$'s classes setup requested in the Claim, as soon as $n$ (odd) is greater than $3$?

I don't have time to think through all the details right now, but I will later hopefully. My plan of attack would be: focus on the Sylow 2-subgroups. A non-trivial central element of one must be the unique one of class size 3. This should be enough to conclude these Sylow 2-subgroups are of size 2, and there are 3 of them, which finishes the problem.

Here's my take.
Let $E_{1}, \dots, E_{n-2}$ be the classes of size $2$.
The intersection $$X = \bigcap_{i} \bigcap_{a \in E_{i}} C_{G}(a)$$ of the centralisers of all elements in these classes is a normal subgroup of index a power of $2$, as each $C_{G}(a)$ has index $2$.
Now the centraliser $Y = C_{G}(X)$ contains at least the $1 + 2 (n-2) = 2n -3$ elements of $$\{ 1 \} \cup \bigcup_{i} E_{i}.$$
If $n > 3$, then $2 n - 3 > n = (2 n)/2$, so by Lagrange's Theorem $Y = G$, so that $X \le Z(G) = \{ 1 \}$, that is $X = \{ 1 \}$, and $G$ is a $2$-group, a contradiction.
Thus $n = 3$.

I think that this argument nicely works more generally for $2n=1+2(n−k)+2k−1$, for every $1<k<\frac{n+1}{2}$. And it rightly "fails" for $k=\frac{n+1}{2}$, as in this case the dihedral group $D_n$ ($n$ odd) is a counterexample.
